# ASP .NET razor website not showing up?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I've published an ASP .NET razor website to the FTP of this domain. However, it doesn't show up at all. Not even if I set the default document to "Default.cshtml".

How come?

The domain is **domain removed since problem is solved** if you want to check out for yourself.

**Edit**

Why on earth am I getting negative votes for this question? Please answer in the comments. I really don't know. Is it because I am linking to my website, or?

**Edit 2**

Please don't vote this post down because I have directory browsing enabled. It's on purpose, and it's my own choice. This website with blank data is the only thing on the server, and there's nothing valuable on it. Furthermore, it's a dedicated server that won't even be used next week.

Comment: Sorry, why am I getting negative votes for this one?

Comment: Your webserver is letting see the directory's content :S You should disallow it inmediatelly

Comment: It's my own choice, for debugging purposes. This is not the server I am going to use anyway for deployment. It's a dedicated test server with nothing valuable on it what so ever.

Comment: @downvoters: Please read the FAQs. It's outrageous that you downvote a question because you *think* that the author should change the configuration of his/her server.

Comment: There is a lot of downvotes on SO these days, I guess it became to popular:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the required files are not on the server. Are you sure the FTP process went ok?

Comment: I didn't have MVC 3 runtimes installed on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that cshtml file (Razor files) can be exposed directly to the user? I use them daily, and they are view templates for ASP.NET applications (ASP.NET MVC more precisely).

Your web server doesn't know how to handle cshtml extensions, and it's rather normal: The more I think about it, the more I am sure that they are really not meant to be used like this. (they don't fill the role of aspx pages)

I strongly suggest you to learn ASP.NET MVC if you want to use razor views:

According to the requested url, MVC fires an action on a controller, which computes all the required informations for page rendering. These informations are then sent to a view (the cshtml razor view), and the view performs the final rendering.

=> Razor is only a part of a more complete infrastructure: It can't be used alone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured IIS? Look at the mime types, default page, and you might want to consider removing directory browsing

Comment: Directory browsing is for debugging. Which mimetypes and default pages do I need for razor?